# how to prevent repeating function in mouse_click event XNA Gamestudio?

Tags: c#, xna, mouseevent

how to prevent repeating function in mouse_click event ?

```
if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
 {
            shoot_sound.Play(); 
            // it plays the sound more than once
            // i'd like to play it just once and stop !
            // how to prevent key repeating 
 }
```

Comment: can you not add something that would hold an initial value of null or zero when first loading then once you click it assign that global variable a 1 or what ever value.. then if the if statement check the value and call shoot_sound.Play() else jump out..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a complete click has occurred or not by this snippet.

```
lastMouseState = currentMouseState;
currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
if (lastMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    // React to the click of the mouse
    shoot_sound.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the code exactly but I think you want something like this..

```
// Create an instance of the sound - makes it easier to manage and deal with
SoundEffectInstance sei = yourSound.CreateInstance();

// then when you go to play the sound make sure it isn't playing before platying it...

if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    if (sei.State == SoundState.Playing)
    {
        yourSound.Play();
    }
}
```

Sorry for jumping straight into an answer before asking but I don't have enough reputation to just comment so please tell me if I'm confused about your question. If it's the looping you're having issues with, try using an oldMouseState and newMouseState technique to check that you're mouse has been clicked and released before playing the sound. Really hope this helps.